# current logged in username in a windows service with WMI

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm using the following code in a windows service to get the current logged user name,

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
strUser = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Its working fine for all the machines but a few machines its returning domainname\domainname\username. 
All other machines its working fine. Any idea?

Comment: if you need only the username, why not just split and select the last?

Comment: @tpaksu: I need both, i'm validating domain\username with database. My  doubt is why its happening for few machines, if we can confirm that its not the machine problem i can check for multiple domain name and remove it, but i'm not sure.

Comment: are you sure that all of them belong to a domain, or logged directly without the domain or not? you would still see them in the network whether they are logged in on the domain or not.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue, its happening only when a user is selecting the domain in the drop down and typing his user name as domain/username in the username text box while logging. Done changes to remove one domain name if it repeat two times.